# PostgreSQL: Disk usage and hardware utilization and performance

Tags: postgresql, insert

In my company we bought a new server

```
AMD EPYC 7262 - 8 core 
64 GB RAM 
Intel SSD DC P4510 (2 TB) - Dedicated only for the database
```

When I benchmarked disk, I got to speed up to 2GB/s for writing and 3GB/s for reading.
[image]

Then I tried performance in Postgres.
I created a table (2 columns integer, 5 columns text, no index) and filled it with a loop. Average text length around 500 characters. And this is speed for 10 000 000 rows.Some 250 MB/s of writing speed.
[image]

Ok, so I guessed maybe the loop is not the best way for writing in Postgres and I tried (This time with 20 000 000 rows.)

```
select * into table2 from table1;
```

then with two independent tables (at the same time = in parallel)

```
select * into table3 from table1; 
select * into table4 from table2;
```

And then with four tables at the same time.

And results were disappointing, because the time required to finish the operation doubled (comparing one insert vs four) and writing speed was getting faster but with poor scaling, not even close to 2x and 4x speed.
I can understand that one insert (aka single thread) won't be able to utilize the entire disk but why does independent insert operations slowing each other when hardware is clearly not the bottleneck and has plenty resources left?

Following printscreens are comparison for the select * into statements I did, showing the time on X axis and speed on Y axis. Then there is disk utilization (way below disk capabilities ) and lastly CPU utilization. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

I asked a bit similar question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846912/postgresql-drop-in-performance-with-multiple-running-functions-without-hardware
Where @jjanes told me about Postgres creating "snapshots" and transaction isolation, and using "repeatable read" to get better performance. But this solution can't be applied here, but I guess the gist of the problem is similar. 
I would be glad if somebody with better knowledge would give me some hints how to tweak performance, because we are running multiple (independent) processes on server very often heavy reading and writing and with this poor scaling we are running them slow while expensive hardware is just chilling.

> PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.3.1
>   20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4), 64-bit
>
> Monitoring software: Zabbix

**EDITS:**
Requests from comment section

1) Code for loop which I used to fill the table, I used the first one with md5 and random. I also decided to try it without them to see if they may slow down the process but when I didn't use them complete opposite happened and write speed drop from previous cca. 250MB/s to around 6MB/s and time to finish the operation multiplied. I truncated the table and repeated it several times (even on different server with different postgres version) but result were the same. No idea what is causing this strange behaviour.

```
create or replace function f_zapis (p_pocet_radku int) 
returns integer as $body$
declare 
v_exc_context text;
p_cislo int := 123456789;
p_text1 text :='';
p_text2 text :='';
p_text3 text :='';
p_text4 text :='';
p_text5 text :='';
p_vata text :='';
begin

p_vata =
$$
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'
$$
;
for i in 1..p_pocet_radku loop

select (random() * 1000000)::int into p_cislo;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text1;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text2;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text3;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text4;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text5;


p_text1 = p_text1 || p_vata;
p_text2 = p_text2 || p_vata;
p_text3 = p_text3 || p_vata;
p_text4 = p_text4 || p_vata;
p_text5 = p_text5 || p_vata;
insert into test_2_zapis (id,cislo,pismena1,pismena2,pismena3,pismena4,pismena5) values(i,p_cislo,p_text1,p_text2,p_text3,p_text4,p_text5);
end loop;

return 1;

exception
  when others then
    get stacked diagnostics v_exc_context = pg_exception_context;
    perform main.ut_log('ERR', sqlerrm || ' [SQL State: ' || sqlstate || '] Context: ' || v_exc_context );
    raise;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql

truncate table test_2_zapis;
select * from f_zapis(1000); --finished in 0.084sec (0.077s, 0.078s)


create or replace function f_zapis (p_pocet_radku int) 
returns integer as $body$
declare 
v_exc_context text;
p_cislo int := 123456789;
p_text1 text :='';
p_text2 text :='';
p_text3 text :='';
p_text4 text :='';
p_text5 text :='';
p_vata text :='';
begin

p_vata =
$$
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'
$$
;
for i in 1..p_pocet_radku loop
/*
select (random() * 1000000)::int into p_cislo;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text1;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text2;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text3;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text4;
SELECT md5(random()::text) into p_text5;
*/

p_text1 = p_text1 || p_vata;
p_text2 = p_text2 || p_vata;
p_text3 = p_text3 || p_vata;
p_text4 = p_text4 || p_vata;
p_text5 = p_text5 || p_vata;
insert into test_2_zapis (id,cislo,pismena1,pismena2,pismena3,pismena4,pismena5) values(i,p_cislo,p_text1,p_text2,p_text3,p_text4,p_text5);
end loop;

return 1;

exception
  when others then
    get stacked diagnostics v_exc_context = pg_exception_context;
    perform main.ut_log('ERR', sqlerrm || ' [SQL State: ' || sqlstate || '] Context: ' || v_exc_context );
    raise;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql

truncate table test_2_zapis;
select * from f_zapis(1000); -- finished in 7.282 sec (7.158s, 7.187s)
------------------------------------------------------
create table test_2_zapis (
id  bigint,
cislo  int,
pismena1  text,
pismena2  text,
pismena3  text,
pismena4  text,
pismena5  text
)
```

2) Table with time results for select into statements, all conditions are same as described above.

- Table size 20,000,000 rows
- If multiple selects run at the same time each has it own source and output table
- All tables has the same data
- I was the only user using the database at that time

[image]

**Notes:**

- time is measured in seconds
- I run the tests multiple times, column *Number of tests*
- result were quite consistent, you can see it from *MIN,MAX,AVG* times
- results are counted on avg values
- if run parallel instances I measured time of each thread (as shown in the table), and then sum them together
- Ideal scaling is based on number of threads
- For real scaling the base is single thread, which is 891 sec, for multithreads it is how much is done by one thread and then multiplied by number of threads
  example 4 threads has speed of 1381 seconds per thread, so one thread does 64,5% of the base single thread, then multiple by 4 (number of threads) and we have 258% done, meaning the scaling 2,58

3) Wait events (for select into statements)

**Wait events time line (single thread)**

https://ibb.co/K9jWLRx

**Wait event time line multi-thread (time line for one out of four threads)**

https://ibb.co/j8wxHYB

Comment: Did you use a transaction per `INSERT` statement? That would explain bad performance. Try prepared statements or `COPY` for even better performance.

Comment: You should sample the "wait_event_type" and "wait_event" columns of pg_stat_activity for these statements while they run.  A pattern might emerge about what they are usually waiting on.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I used `select * into table2 from table1;` and for the loop I used "classic" insert into statement ... copy tables is not what I need (but I will try it for the purpose of benchmarking), I need faster inserts and mainly inserts that does not slow each other

Comment: @jjanes "Could you give us the actual numbers and/or ratios here?" you can see it on the print screens, mainly the first one, you can see the speed on Y axis and time length on X axis, they show the select into statements I did, for one table, two tables at once and four tables at once, they show that time for four insert got doubled and speed is some 600MB+ while it should be 1200MB+ if scaled ideally  ... and I will ad the pg_stat information into my post

Comment: Not all CPU, or all IO, is equally productive.  Seeing the monitoring values for those doesn't really answer my question.  You can kind of tell from the duration on the X axis, how much of that time at the end is while the command is running, versus the command being done and checkpoints (or something else) trying to catch up?

Comment: Please show more details. In which programming language is the loop that runs the `INSERT`s? Can you show the code? Are you using a single client or several that work concurrently?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I edited my post and added the loop I used to fill the table, also some strange behaviour happened, I described it in the edit. ..... and for running the `select into`   I used my client (DbVisualizer) and run each instance in different window, so it send all of them at the same time on server in it's own connection.

Comment: @jjanes I will measure the time and create table how much it takes to finish for each scenario and then edit my post

Comment: That will be nice, but a summary of wait_event and wait_event_type sampling will probably be more important.  (Of course you can do both at the same time, since both require you to repeat the exercise)

Comment: @jjanes I added table with times for scaling, and also time line with wait events, .. could you also please have a look on the loop function I posted, there is very strange behavior where adding hash and random function makes it run 100x faster (or better to say removing them made it 100x slower)

Comment: I just realized I don't think you gave the version.  Or at least, I can't find it in what is now a very long question.  Could you add a tag?  This is important as multi-core scalability has been a big push in recent years.

Comment: "there is very strange behavior where adding hash and random function makes it run 100x faster"  This is an entirely separate question, it might make sense to ask it as such.  With the use of `perf`, I can see that the slow one spends nearly all its time trying to compress the fields (for TOAST).  I don't why the compression is so much slower in one case than the other.

Comment: @jjanes I did provide the version of Postgres it was at the end of my post, but due to the edits and additional information you probably missed it, anyway it is PostgreSQL 12.2, and I also gave the info about the monitoring tool (it is Zabbix) ... I will edit my post and move the wait events screens to external site and put the links so it will make my post bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

What tool did you use for benchmarking the IO, and with what settings?

If it is multi-threaded, that might be the "problem".  Writing WAL records is an inherently single-threaded process (different processes can do it, but they use locks so only one process can do it at a time), so a multi-threaded benchmark may not be the relevant benchmark to use.

Does your benchmark insert fsync into the writes?  Large transactions like bulk copies don't fsync often (unlike short transactions) but they still fsync once per WAL file, 16 MB by default.  And 16 MB doesn't take very long when doing bulk inserts.  You can set the size of WAL files during `initdb`, or on newer versions change the size with `pg_resetwal --wal-segsize` (warning: pg_resetwal is very dangerous.  I'd only use in test systems in which case you usually might as just initdb instead)

It looks like the wait_events in your single threaded case are about half IO.  That is odd to me.  I would have expected them to be 90% NULL (meaning essentially 'CPU').  This fact make me wonder how much scaling you can expect to get.

Also, your rows alternative almost perfectly between NULL and not NULL.  I would expect a statistical process here, not a metronome. I don't need to pull out my stats book to declare that your runs of length 1 way too common to come from a statistical process.  But I don't know what to do with this conclusion, so I will ignore it.

On your 4 process data, on the other hand, I would have expected way more IO events and almost no NULL/CPU events.  There are a lot of IO event, but not as many as I would have thought by eyeballing it.

By the way, why stop at 4?  7262 apparently has 8 real CPUs (not that hyperthreading crap which never seems to do anything useful, for databases anyway).  Cranking it up to 8 might make patterns clearer.  Cranking it up to 80, on the other hand, will just find bottlenecks that are irrelevant at reasonable settings, so don't do that.

Here would be my research program:

- Upgrade to 12.3 if you are not already on it.
  No point in discovering problems that have already been improved.
- set wal_writer_flush_after = 0
  if it doesn't improve things at all, I might set it back.  I can't decide
- Increase wal-segsize
- Turn off fsync (not on production!)
- Make your tables unlogged/temp
- If still not scaling, move your tables to different databases (kind of a long shot)
- And if still not scaling, create several instances and put one table in each instance.

Many of these can't be used as a solution, but can at least provide some insight into the problem, which can then lead to solutions.